# Ratio in Fractional Form

Tags: fractions, rational-numbers

I have 3 puppies and 2 piglets.
Can you that ratio be written in this fractional form 5/2?
If yes, how would you describe this ratio as 5/2?

Comment: *"that ratio"* Which ratio? As currently worded, the question is not answerable. Please also add some context to point out how it is a question about math education rather than about mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

In order to judge whether $5/2$ is correct, you need to specify which ratio you're talking about. There are a lot of ratios that can be made here, one of which is $5/2.$ (There are $3+2=5$ animals in total, so the ratio of total animals to piglets is $5/2.$)

I'm guessing the correct answer you have in mind is $3/2,$ which is indeed one of the possible ratios here (and probably the most natural ratio), but the question would need to specify that it's asking for the ratio of puppies to piglets.